# Error when Importing Statsmodels in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, statsmodels

I'm currently trying to fit an ARMA model to some data, using the statsmodels module in Python. The problem is, however, that it fails to load the package, and just returns an `AttributeError` which states:

```
  File "C:\Projects\Python\KalmanFilteringDataFusion\armaTest.py", line 5, in <module>
    from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\arima_model.py", line 30, in <module>
    from statsmodels.tsa.ar_model import AR
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\ar_model.py", line 608, in <module>
    class ARResults(tsbase.TimeSeriesModelResults):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\ar_model.py", line 811, in ARResults
    preddoc = AR.predict.__doc__.split('\n')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

The only thing i'm doing, is trying to import the ARIMA module as:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
```

If i try to import another statmodels sub-module (ex. `import statsmodels.formula.api as smf`) it returns:

```
  File "C:\Projects\Python\KalmanFilteringDataFusion\armaTest.py", line 5, in <module>
    import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\formula\api.py", line 15, in <module>
    from statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model import MNLogit
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\discrete\discrete_model.py", line 146, in <module>
    class DiscreteModel(base.LikelihoodModel):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\discrete\discrete_model.py", line 208, in DiscreteModel
    fit.__doc__ += base.LikelihoodModel.fit.__doc__
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

If i just do `import statsmodels` or `import statsmodels.tsa` it imports it just fine, so i guess that the error lies somewhere in the ARIMA "sub-module".

Does anybody have any suggestions as to what is wrong? And any potential fix to it?

Comment: How did you install *statsmodels*, and which version is it?

Comment: Using pip, through Visual Studio. That might be the issue. The version is 0.8.0.

Comment: I tried to uninstall Python completely, and re-install it (not through VS), and it returns the same error. Python version 3.6.5

Comment: Does your *pip* installation succeed? I only see the source package for *Win*. I just installed for *Python35 x64* and it works.

Comment: I guess this is https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/4242

Comment: @CristiFati do you compile the package yourself or? The pip install returns a "success", but that might be the case.

Comment: Even if i compile the package myself (by downloading it, and running `python setup.py install` it returns the same error.

Comment: Did you look in the *ar\_model.py* file at `AR.predict` function? What comes after the function header? Or try installing *Python3.5* and see if it works with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using Sublime Text 3 to compile Python, and apparantly the "Python3" build file, was causing the error. When i switched to the "Python"-builder, the system compiled just fine. Except for a few warning about pandas dropping support for the way DateTime is implemented in statsmodels.

If you're stuck in the same situation, try switching builder. I'll keep you posted when i figure out why that was the case. Cause it was really weird.